# How to eliminate flickering in a simple image viewer made with wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I've created a simple image viewer using wxPython, but I'm experiencing flickering when the images are changed using the arrow keys. How can I fix this issue? Here's the code I've written so far:

```
import wx
import os
import glob

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, title="Image Viewer", size=(800, 600))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)

        self.images = []
        self.image_index = -1
        self.image_path = None

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.on_key_down)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.on_size)
        self.SetFocus()

    def on_key_down(self, event):
        keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
        if keycode == wx.WXK_LEFT:
            if self.image_index > 0:
                self.image_index -= 1
                self.image_path = self.images[self.image_index]
                self.display_image(self.image_path)
        elif keycode == wx.WXK_RIGHT:
            if self.image_index < len(self.images) - 1:
                self.image_index += 1
                self.image_path = self.images[self.image_index]
                self.display_image(self.image_path)
        event.Skip()

    def on_size(self, event):
        if self.image_path:
            self.display_image(self.image_path)
        event.Skip()

    def display_image(self, path):
        self.image_path = path
        self.panel.Refresh()
        self.panel.Update()

    def on_paint(self, event):
        if self.image_path:
            image = wx.Image(self.image_path, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)

            # Resize the image to fit the window size
            window_width, window_height = self.panel.GetClientSize()
            image_width, image_height = image.GetSize()
            scale = min(window_width / image_width, window_height / image_height)
            new_width = int(image_width * scale)
            new_height = int(image_height * scale)
            image = image.Scale(new_width, new_height, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)

            bitmap = wx.Bitmap(image)
            dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self.panel)
            dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(self.panel.GetBackgroundColour()))
            dc.DrawBitmap(bitmap, (window_width - new_width) // 2, (window_height - new_height) // 2, True)

    def load_images(self, filename):
        supported_extensions = ('*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.png', '*.bmp', '*.gif')
        self.images = []
        for ext in supported_extensions:
            self.images.extend(sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename), ext), recursive=True)))
        if filename in self.images:
            self.image_index = self.images.index(filename)
        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"Specified image not found: {filename}")

    def select_image(self):
        wildcard = "Image files (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp;*.gif"
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open image", wildcard=wildcard, style=wx.FD_OPEN)

        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.image_path = dialog.GetPath()
            self.load_images(self.image_path)
            self.display_image(self.image_path)

        dialog.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show()

    frame.select_image()

    app.MainLoop()
```

So far, we've tried several methods to eliminate flickering when changing images using the arrow keys in your simple image viewer:

1. Calling Refresh() and Update() methods on the panel after displaying a new image.
   2 . Using wx.BufferedPaintDC instead of wx.PaintDC in the on_paint() method to reduce flickering by double buffering.
2. Setting the background color of the wx.BufferedPaintDC to match the panel's background color.
3. Attempting to use wx.BufferedDC_None, but this resulted in an error as wx does not have an attribute called BufferedDC_None.

Comment: Hello! Have you tried moving the calls to `Refresh()` and `Update()` at the end of `on_pain()` method?

Comment: Thank you for response! yes, i tried that. But it was very slow to display images.

Comment: Have you tried `self.panel.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_PAINT)`? See https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Window.html#wx.Window.SetBackgroundStyle

Comment: Don't call ```Update()``` manually. Don't load an image file at the ```EVT_PAINT``` handler. You don't need to use the ```BufferedPaintDC```, instead of the ```PaintDC```. The ```dc.SetBackground()``` is useless if you don't call the ```dc.Clear()```.

Answer (score 0):

I would rework it a bit:

```
import wx
import os
import glob

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, title="Image Viewer", size=(800, 600))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.on_erase)

        self.images = []
        self.image_index = -1
        self.image = None

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.on_key_down)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.on_size)
        self.SetFocus()

    def on_key_down(self, event):
        keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
        if keycode == wx.WXK_LEFT:
            if self.image_index > 0:
                self.image_index -= 1
                image_path = self.images[self.image_index]
                self.display_image(image_path)
        elif keycode == wx.WXK_RIGHT:
            if self.image_index < len(self.images) - 1:
                self.image_index += 1
                image_path = self.images[self.image_index]
                self.display_image(image_path)
        event.Skip()

    def on_size(self, event):
        self.panel.Refresh()
        event.Skip()

    def display_image(self, path):
        self.image = wx.Image(path, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        self.panel.Refresh()

    def on_paint(self, event):
        if not self.image:
            return  # No image
        
        # Resize the image to fit the window size
        window_width, window_height = self.panel.GetClientSize()
        image_width, image_height = self.image.GetSize()
        scale = min(window_width / image_width, window_height / image_height)
        new_width = int(image_width * scale)
        new_height = int(image_height * scale)
        image = self.image.Scale(new_width, new_height, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)

        bitmap = wx.Bitmap(image)
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self.panel)
        x0 = (window_width - new_width) // 2
        y0 = (window_height - new_height) // 2
        x1 = x0 + new_width
        y1 = y0 + new_height

        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(self.panel.GetBackgroundColour()))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(self.panel.GetBackgroundColour()))
        if x0 > 0:
            dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, x0, window_height)
        if x1 < window_width:
            dc.DrawRectangle(x1, 0, window_width-x1, window_height)
        if y0 > 0:
            dc.DrawRectangle(x0, 0, new_width, y0)
        if y1 < window_height:
            dc.DrawRectangle(x0, y1, new_width, window_height-y1)

        dc.DrawBitmap(bitmap, x0, y0, True)
            
    def on_erase(self, event):
        pass

    def load_images(self, filename):
        supported_extensions = ('*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.png', '*.bmp', '*.gif')
        self.images = []
        for ext in supported_extensions:
            self.images.extend(sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename), ext), recursive=True)))
        if filename in self.images:
            self.image_index = self.images.index(filename)
        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"Specified image not found: {filename}")

    def select_image(self):
        wildcard = "Image files (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp;*.gif"
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open image", wildcard=wildcard, style=wx.FD_OPEN)

        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            image_path = dialog.GetPath()
            self.load_images(image_path)
            self.display_image(image_path)

        dialog.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show()

    frame.select_image()

    app.MainLoop()
```

Major Changes:

- I block the redraw of the window background (see the empty OnErase handler)
- The OnSize handler only calls Refresh
- I only load the image once in the display_image function
- I erase the background of the window using dc.DrawRectangle
- I draw the background of the window only where it is not covered by the picture